# Styled Components cannot set :hover properties

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, styled-components

```js
export const WatchVideoButtonWrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    right: 33px;
    background-color: ${(props) => props.bgColor};
    color: ${(props) => props.color};
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: ${(props) => props.color};
    &:hover {
        background-color: ${(props) => props.hoverBgColor};
        color: ${(props) => props.hoverColor};
        fill: ${(props) => props.hoverColor};
    }
`;
```

And I am passing the props as such:

```js
<WatchVideoButtonWrapper
            bgColor={navbar_button_background_color}
            color={navbar_button_text_and_icon_color}
            hoverBgColor={navbar_button_hover_background_color}
            hoverColor={navbar_button_hover_text_and_icon_color}
>
...
</WatchVideoButtonWrapper>
```

Everything works except the hover state.  I want to implement a simple css animation when the div is hovered, but using styled components.  I have referred to the documentation and it seems all I need is `&:hover {}` inside the styled component.  SO... the styles load and the background color and text color is correct, but when hovered, the effect is not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing it a a higher z-index ? may be there is a block in front of your element that is preventing the pointer from interacting with it ? just a first idea...

Comment: Thank you so much, it never occurred to me to adjust the z-index or that something could be obstructing interaction from the mouse.  This fixed my issue :)

Comment: good news !! happy i could help out :)